# Oracle XE: Admin can't access a user's tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, system-administration

So I've connected to Oracle XE 11g as the administrator (system). I create a new user Bob and wish to grant only certain privileges to him on a certain table. The table in mind was created by another ordinary user Jim.

When I try to grant, I am told that the "table or view" does not exist"? If I log in as Jim the table exists, but as system I cannot seem to access tables created by Jim.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you using the Schema/User-name in front of the table name? Like `Schemaname.Tablename` ?

Answer (score 2):

be sure to specify the schemaname in the grant DDL otherwise it will first look in the system schema for the table, and failing that look for a synonym to resolve the table name.

i.e.

```
SQL> connect system/@oracle11203
Connected.

SQL> grant select on TESTTAB to TEST2;
grant select on TESTTAB to TEST2
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> grant select on TEST.TESTTAB to TEST2;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Comment: Oh, I'm not aware of the schema. I'm new to Oracle. As the user Jim I just created tables, I never specified a schema. Are they under some default schema?

Comment: @user2119522 you do know the schema, as you said yourself "The table in mind was created by another ordinary user Jim." ie the schema is JIM (users and schemas are the same thing in oracle). so if you created the table logged in a JIM, then JIM owns the table so grant `grant select on JIM.YOUR_TAB to BOB;`